# JSLint warning: `Expected ':' and instead saw '='

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have a go to top button that appears when user has scrolled down on the page. The button works as intended but in JLint, it gives a warning: `Expected ':' and instead saw '='.` How do I correct the code:

```
var topBtn = document.createElement("button");
topBtn.innerHTML = "Top";

var topBtnWrapper = document.getElementById("topBtnWrap");
topBtnWrapper.appendChild(topBtn);

window.onscroll = function() {
  ((document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) ? topBtn.style.display = "block" : topBtn.style.display = "none");
};
```

Comment: `topBtn.style.display = (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) ? "block" : "none";`

Comment: checking just `document.documentElement.scrollTop` seems enough .. I don't see any reason for checking `document.body.scrollTop` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
((document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) ? topBtn.style.display = "block" : topBtn.style.display = "none");
```

This appears to be a ternary operator, but ternary as a way to decide which value to use instead of which statement to run.

This could be better represented as an if-else block:

```
if (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {
    topBtn.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    topBtn.style.display = 'none';
}
```

If you wanted to keep using a ternary operator, this is how it would look:

```
topBtn.style.display = document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500
    ? 'block'
    : 'none';
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean this:

```
topBtn.style.display = document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500
    ? "block" 
    : "none";
```

The ternary operator is not meant to be a flow control structure.

Answer (score 2):

The format for a ternary operator is:

```
x = condition ? option1 : option2
```

not:

```
condition ? x = option1 : x = option2
```

Your code should look like:

```
topBtn.style.display = 
    (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) 
        ? "block" 
        : "none";
```